# Retrieving image icon for the objects saved after deserialization

Tags: java, arrays, object, deserialization, imageicon

-The array of appliances(clock,lamp or television) is displayed on an array of labels (pictures[]) in a 3x3 grid

-An example of outputting an appliance icon (which is when a device is added to the grid though a button labelled 'add device')

```
Television myTelevision = new Television();
                appliance[count-1] = myTelevision;                
                pictures[count-1].setIcon(appliance[count-1].getPicture());
```

This is my code for saving the array of appliances (objects) to a file and reading them back in ( re-populating the appliance array):

```
    if(e.getSource()==but3)
    {  
        ObjectInputStream input 
            = null;
        try {
            input = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream("livingroom.bat"));
            Appliance[] appliance = (Appliance[]) (input.readObject());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }




    }


    if(e.getSource()==but4)
    {
        ObjectOutputStream output 
            = null;
        try {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream("livingroom.bat", true));
            output.writeObject(appliance);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

After deserialization I am trying to display the imageicon for the appliances in the array (which has just been re-populated). However no matter how I try nothing seems to happen (the grid of pictures shows no change).

**What I am asking for:** Can anyone tell me a method of applying the image icons for the appliances to the grid of pictures once deserialization has taken place?

Answer (score 0):

You are deserialising into a local variable whose scope ends with the `try` block it is declared in, and you don't do anything with the local variable, so nothing happens.

Presumably you should be deserialing into a member variable.